# Unit testing with Effort - Adding records with identity off

Tags: unit-testing, mstest, objectcontext, effort

I am using using Effort (for EF4) to do some unit tests.

```
var ctx= Effort.ObjectContextFactory.CreateTransient<TheContext>(Shared.Connection);
ctx.companies.AddObject(new company() { ID = 100, name = "Agent", is_agent = true });
ctx.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
```

The ID column in the company is an identity field. After executing the above query, it turns out the ID value is 1 instead of 100. Is there any way to control Identity_insert while using Effort

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @tjhazel This has been solved for later version. You can find more details  [here](https://effort.codeplex.com/discussions/430306)

Comment: I'm interested in this issue too - unfortunately @MJK the link you provided is dead.  Can you by any chance fix it...?

Comment: Update: found it archived on the Wayback Machine at https://web.archive.org/web/20150202074618/http://effort.codeplex.com:80/discussions/430306

Comment: I think the key API call referenced in that thread is EffortConnection.DbConfiguration.SetIdentityFields(false) - but I can't find this method on the current version of Effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to add the solution on this thread. @MrBlueSky add the [archieved links](http://found%20it%20archived%20on%20the%20Wayback%20Machine%20at) of the solution on the comments above. But, `DbConfiguration` which is used on the link, does not exists anymore on the latest Effort. The solution still exists on `Effort.EF6 [version="1.3.0"]`. And you can use the method `SetIdentityFields` on `EffortConnection.DbManager` to turn on or off the identity fields

```
if (Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient() is EffortConnection connection)
{
    connection.Open();
    connection.DbManager.SetIdentityFields(false);
    connection.DbManager.ClearMigrationHistory();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Turning on

```
// Add data with explicitly set id
Person initPerson = new Person { Id = 5, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
dataInitContext.People.Add(initPerson);
dataInitContext.SaveChanges();

Assert.AreEqual(5, initPerson.Id);

// Enable identity field
connection.Open();
connection.DbManager.SetIdentityFields(true);
connection.Close();
```